# Windows service with Apache Commons Daemon set automatically to start

Tags: java, windows-services, apache-commons

I use Apache Commons Daemon to make my Java program run as a windows service.
I want the service to start automatically after installation, i.e: Startup Type will be 'Automatically' and Service Status will be 'Started'.

I managed to make the Startup Type 'Automatically' (by the param: `--Startup=auto`), but it does not start automatically. I have to manually click on 'Start' button at the first time and only then it works.

How can I set the Status to be 'Started' without the user has to start is manually?

---

Here is my full deployment line:

```
myService.exe //IS//MyService --Install=C:\MyService\bin\myService.exe --Description="My Java Service" --Jvm=auto --Classpath=C:\MyService\classes --StartMode=jvm --StartClass=Test.Service.MyService --StartMethod=windowsService --StartParams=start --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=Test.Service.MyService --StopMethod=windowsService --StopParams=stop --LogPath=C:\MyService\logs --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto --Startup=auto
```

---

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to do restart..
I forgot to do it, and that is why the service hasn't started.